# Counting co-occurence of strings in lists of lists

Tags: r, list

Assume I have a list of lists like follows:

```
$`1`
[1] "John"
[2] "Maria"

$`2`
[1] "John"
[2] "Maria"

$`3`
[1] "John"
[2] "Carlos"
```

Then we are trying to figure out which names have occurred together, in a sublist. I.e. "John" and "Maria" occurred together twice, so sublists with their names should get a score of 2, whereas "John" and "Carlos" occurred together once and should get a score of 1. The expected out put would be:

```
$`1`
[1] 2

$`2`
[1] 2

$`3`
[1] 1
```

Also, assume that there could be unlimited number of names in each sublist. The key is to identify instances where two names occur together more than once, and then give them an additional "point" for each time they co-occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first generate all pairs of names in the lists using `lapply` with `combn`:

```
(pdat <- lapply(dat, function(x) {
  y <- combn(sort(x), 2)
  paste(y[1,], y[2,])
}))
# [[1]]
# [1] "John Maria"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "John Maria"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "Carlos John"
```

Then I would generate the number of each pair with `table` and `unlist`:

```
(tab <- table(unlist(pdat)))
# Carlos John  John Maria 
#           1           2
```

Finally I would compute the scores for each element in the list by summing their frequencies:

```
sapply(pdat, function(x) sum(tab[x]))
# [1] 2 2 1
```

Data:

```
(dat <- list(c("John", "Maria"), c("John", "Maria"), c("John", "Carlos")))
# [[1]]
# [1] "John"  "Maria"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "John"  "Maria"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "John"   "Carlos"
```